# How to remove blueback from cables?

Tags: cleaning

I currently have some blueback that is stuck on a cable that I own. Normally, you can use blueback to remove blueback. This does not work in my case. I have also tried scraping it off with my nail. This still doesn't work. I even tried to wet the blueback to make it softer, I still could not scratch it off.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can we assume that "blueback" is actually "blu tack"...?

Comment: Close enough. I would say it is slightly harder than blueback but close.

Comment: OK, I've never heard of it. With Blu Tack, the problem is that the oil evaporates away over the course of a few years. I think I might try adding some new, fresh Blu Tack in the hope that the oil penetrates it. It will probably take days rather than minutes I would imagine.

Answer (score 1):

Blue tack cant be pulled off try rolling it off the cable also in extreme conditions use nail polish remover(acetone)but then you cant reuse it. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the cable is not too large you could place it in the freezer. Assuming that the cable is copper based this should not harm it. After a day or so you can take the cable out and gently but with enough force give the offending substance a few blows with a hammer. The cold should have caused it to become brittle. You may need to use a bit of elbow grease to get the last thin layers off though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get it soft enough with heat or light to just peel it off.